# fish equivalent for sequence of commands -- { cmd1 ; cmd2; }

Tags: fish

In bash, you can pipe the same output to two commands using `{}`, i.e. in the following:

```
cmd0 | { cmd1 ; cmd2 ;} | cmd3
```

cmd1 and cmd2 get the output of cmd0 in their stdin, and cmd3 gets the output of cmd2 appended to output of cmd2 in its stdin.

What's the name of this `{}` feature and is there an equivalent in fish?

Comment: What exactly does "fish" stand for? Could you please provide a link to make it unambiguous? Did you take into account wether and why you really need to script this in "fish"?

Comment: @Nepumuk did you check the tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is called *command grouping*.

In the [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/), it appears to be provided by using `begin` and `end` in place of bash's `{` and `}` braces - a feature I only discovered from a bug report:

- [begin-end command grouping isn't discoverable/documented prominently enough #6415](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/6415)

Note that regardless of shell, the first command that is able to do so will consume standard input ex.

(`bash`):

```
$ echo foo | { sed 's/oo/aa/'; sed 's/oo/um/'; }
faa
```

(`fish`):

```
> echo foo | begin sed 's/oo/aa/'; sed 's/oo/um/'; end
faa
```

but

```
> echo foo | begin echo cmd1 ; sed 's/oo/um/'; end
cmd1
fum
```